# Which among the following is true for a diffrentiable function $f$?

Tags: real-analysis, continuity

Let $f: [a,b] \to \mathbb{R}$ be a differentiable function such that there does NOT exist any $x \in [a,b]$ for which $f(x) = f'(x) =0$

Let $A = (x \in [a,b] :f(x) = 0)$ be non empty then $A$ is

(a)Compact

(b)Closed

(c) Necessarily Finite

(d) Open.

Since Under Continuous Map ,inverse Image of a Closed Set is Closed I have proved that option (a) and (b) are True , while (d) is clearly false,

However I am not able to prove whether (c) is right or wrong. Intuitively I feel that it must be correct.

How can I prove/disprove option (c) ?

Any Hints ??

Answer (score 1):

Set $a=-1, b=1$, then the continuous extension of the function $f$ – given by $f(x) = x^3 \sin(1/x)$, $x\neq 0$ – onto $[a,b]$ is $C^1$ (mean value theorem), but has infinitely many zeros which are neither local extrema nor saddle points.